# Max of array of enumeration

Tags: arrays, typescript, enums

Say I have an enum

```
enum enumerationTmp {
  a, // 0
  b, // 1
  c  // 2
}
```

and a list of these

```
const letters = [enumerationTmp.a, enumerationTmp.b]
```

How do I get the max of letters?

```
maxLetters = enumerationTmp.b // as b = 1 and a = 0
```

Comment: `Math.max(...letters);`?

Comment: that would do it @zerkms

Comment: @p.s.w.g yes it is, I'll change the tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given enumeration values are numbers - general mathematical operations and functions would do:

```
const maxLetters = Math.max(...letters);
```

References:

- [MDN :: Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)